# How to shade the area under a straight line graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How do I shade the area under a straight line graph in Excel, along the *x*-axis? The graph data points are shown below.

```
0-16.67
170-16.67
170-6.712
187.5-6.712
652-25.352
670-33.408
910-33.408
910-0
```

I have tried using area plot and selecting time for the *x*-axis, but the values on the *x*-axis differ from the real data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill an area between two lines in a chart in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/233027/fill-an-area-between-two-lines-in-a-chart-in-excel)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  When you say the values on the X-axis differ from the real data, do you mean that the values aren't scaled correctly (i.e. the space between 0-170 is the same as 170-187)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these data points are listed as (x,y) and you are looking for a graph with an area plot.

> 'I have tried using area plot and selecting time for the x-axis, but the values on the x-axis differ from the real data.'

This might be because the data for x and y axis might be incorrectly selected.

Once you have inserted an area chart in excel, navigate to `Select Data` and in place of Horizontal (x-axis) choose the range for 0, 170, 170, 187.5..

The chart finally looks like this:

[image]